# Error inflating Spinner (Binary XML file line)

Tags: android, spinner

my xml :

```
 <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/nSpinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
```

in my code :

```
(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.nSpinner));
```

gradle :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
```

It works on Android 8,9 but it crash on android 5.1 on Samsung J3 and Huawei with :

```
 Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class Spinner
```

This error points to my

How can i fix?
Than

Comment: Please post the complete stacktrace, including the nested "caused by" exceptions.

Comment: this part of stacktrace is not usefull. Post full stacktrace and full xml

Comment: can you put whole XML and Java code?

Comment: i find the problem and is disappointing : that spinner was part of my custom pop-up; All initialization of that popup ( context, listener, findviewbyid ... ) was done using rxjava on other thread. The popup was trigger to show in main thread ;  To make it work without any crash i have to make everything on main thread. Is there any workaround ?